# How to compare daily active data to cumulative data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, hypothesis-test

so I am working on COVID-19 data of the state of Texas, USA.
I have been given 2 hypotheses to work on

1. A higher hospitalization rate gives a higher fatality rate
2. A higher ICU rate gives a higher fatality rate.

Fatality Data - https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/TexasCOVID19DailyCountyFatalityCountData.xlsx

Hospitalization / ICU Data - https://dshs.texas.gov/coronavirus/CombinedHospitalDataoverTimebyTSA.xlsx

So the basic approach to proving these hypotheses should be to compare Cumulative/per day Fatality data vs cumulative/per day hospitalization / ICU Data.

The main issue with this is fatality data is given cumulative cumsum while hospitalization/icu data is active number per day. Is there anyway these two can be compared if yes then how? Or is there anything we can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

A cumulated data is the cumsum version of a per-day data, and reciprocally, a per-day data is a differential cumsum data.

I assume the number of cumulated fatalities is accumulated per day, so you can extract the per-day # of fatalities with differential (e.g. `np.diff`). This way, every data will be a daily number. Note that in this case, you will end up with one missing point (at the end).

You can also decide to accumulate the # of hospitalization or ICU data with cumsum to be compared with the cumulated # of facilities.

Comment: What you said seems reasonable but as I said the # of hospitalization or ICU data is basically what is total number of active cases per day it is more like this.  

Day 1 - 17 people got admitted     

Day 2 - 17 people (but the possibility here can be 2 people discharged and 2 new patient) So in this case active live hospitalization per day is giving me hard time.    

Day 3 - 13 people hospilized (There are many possibilities like 4 people getting discharged or 6 people getting discharged while 2 more admitted)  

So cumsum for this is not possible in this case

Comment: The thing is: you don't know. That's why you need to put them on the same time basis and compare. You cannot infer the # of new patients, the ones that healed, and so. You want to test the hypothesis "a higher hospitalization rate gives a higher facility rate". So you just need to plot them (derivative or antiderivative) if you want to check visually. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ahh okay I got what you are trying to say this is how my plot looks like.
https://github.com/Data-Analytics-COVID-Hypothesis/Hypothesis-1/blob/master/hype1.ipynb

Can you just have a look and just confirm this is what you meant.

Comment: By eyes, we see on your plot that the red curve is roughly the anti-derivative of the blue curve (around May for instance, the increase in cumulated # of fatalities corresponds to an increase of the daily # of hospitalizations). You should whether differentiate the fatalities against time (with e.g. `np.diff`, do not forget to drop the last element of the time vector in order to match the shape), or with accumulate the # of hospitalizations (with np.cumsum).

Comment: Now when I do np.diff() for the fatalities the two plots become uncomparable we cannot see any relationship in that Everything is just some random numbers jumping up and down without any relationship in it